# Show Only 10 records in gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, linq, gridview

I'm using ASP.net and I have a gridview which get data from Linq. I need to only show 10 records (Top 10 records).

Comment: Then `data.Take(10)` should work. You should provide more informations. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the take method:

```
(from q in context.Results
select q).Take(10)
```

You can also skip to skip some previous records:

```
(from q in context.Results
select q).Skip(10).Take(10)
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the same or not but I have tried like this:return myProductList.AsQueryable<Top10ProductView>().OrderByDescending(od => od.QuantitySold).Skip(10).Take(10); and it does't work

Comment: Try reversing what you are doing, like: myProductList.OrderByDescending(od => od.QuantitySold).Skip(10).Take(10).AsQueryable<Top10ProductView>();

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Enumerable.Take**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) to get top records from query of set [`PageSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagesize.aspx) of gridview page to ten. You will not to set `AllowPaging` to true as well to take the PageSize affect.

Using linQ

```
context.YourTable.Take(10);
```

Setting size of gridview

```
gridView1.PageSize = 10;
```

Comment: Did you set AllowPaging to true?

Comment: yes I have another tables with pages, so I know how thats works, but when I tried to stop the page to 10 records only, it doesn't work